# Telegram api. Не могу найти api или другие способы позволяющее переименовывать контакты

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, api, контакты

Не могу найти ни библиотеки ни способы какие бы помогли переименовывать контакты в телеграмме. Пишу сейчас программу и хочу через api (в крайнем случае через другие инструменты) переименовывать контакты. Например контакт зовут "Василий Пупкин", хочу переименовать "Василилий англ яз 20 ур строительства Пупкин". Может быть и не питон. И таких контактов очень много. Если это нельзя реализовать через api, или через python, могут быть другими языками программирования или интсрументами.